# Userform - VBA code compile error: User-defined type not defined

Tags: excel, vba, userform, user-defined

I managed to form a VBA code which can auto import exchange rate data from website as below. It works perfectly week in the individual worksheet.
But I am facing a challenge how to add this code into my main development userform.
My idea is to add in this VBA code as command button in my main development userform as command button named "Exchange Rate" and click on it and it will auto import the exchange rate data from website into excel worksheet named "Exchange Rate".

1. I try to add this VBA code as below in my main development userform code as a command button "Exchange Rate" to execute the function display the data in my Worksheet "ExchangeRate" but it compile error: User-defined type not defined.

Appreciate someone can guide me to find out what is the error.
Below is the code i trying to add into my main development userform

main development userform code:https://drive.google.com/file/d/10i5KoqXnTMrh49bYvDTMYBDn1g-D5DEl/view?usp=sharing

```
Sub ExchangeRate()
Dim ieObj As InternetExplorer
Dim htmlEle As IHTMLElement
Dim htmlEleCollection As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim i As Integer


i = 1

Set ieObj = New InternetExplorer
ieObj.Visible = True
ieObj.navigate "https://www.imf.org/external/np/fin/ert/GUI/Pages/Report.aspx?CU=%27SGD%27&EX=REP&P=OneWeek&CF=Compressed&CUF=Period&DS=Ascending&DT=Blank"

While ieObj.readyState <> 4 Or ieObj.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

Set htmlEleCollection = ieObj.document.getElementsByClassName("default").Item(0).getElementsByClassName("row1")

For Each htmlEle In htmlEleCollection
    If htmlEle.Children.Length > 1 Then

       With ActiveSheet
           .Range("A" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(0).textContent
           .Range("B" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(1).textContent
       End With
    End If

    i = i + 1

Next htmlEle
End Sub
```

Comment: You're likely missing a reference in your VBA project

Comment: Read here about early and late binding: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/binding-type-available-to-automation-clients